# MongoDB text search and geoWithin search

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, geospatial

I know that MongoDB does not support searching by `text index` and `geospatial index` at the same time, as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883260/mongodb-combine-text-search-and-geospatial-query). But I saw suggestions to use `$geoWithin` instead of `$near`. I am using `$geoWithin` with `$box geometry` and it doesn't yield any results. However, when I use `$geoWithin` and `$center` geometry, it does work. What may be wrong? Is it not supported? Is it a bug? Of course that if I apply those query conditions separately (text and geo spatial), it all works.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is mentioned several times in documentation that `$geoWithin` does not require geospatial index. I could not make it work with `$box` operator.

This is not working:

```
db.getCollection('Article').find({
    "coordinates": {
        $geoWithin: {
            $box: [
                [13.2680001, 49.805786],
                [13.4758465, 49.6776084]
            ]
        }
    },    
    $text: {
        $search: "Lorem ipsum"
    }
})
```

Pretty easy workaround is to use `$gte` and `$lte` operators instead.

Working solution:

```
db.getCollection('Article').find({
    "coordinates.longitude": { $gte: 13.2680001, $lte: 13.4758465 },
    "coordinates.latitude": { $gte: 49.6776084, $lte: 49.805786 },
    $text: {
        $search: "Lorem ipsum"
    }
})
```

I, however, am not sure about performance of such query.